# How to make search by few user id in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, userid

In my iOS project i need to find bugs for group of some users. I know they user id in Crashlytics. I can find bugs separately for each of them by user id, but i need to find bugs in group because there are more than 100 users in group and there are several such group. Can somebody help with this?

I try to add list of user id in search window but is does't work.

Comment: I don't think you can search for a list of user IDs in the Crashlytics dashboard. If those groups have an ID or something like that, you could try saving customs keys with the group ID and then search by that. Or export the data to BigQuery and make your own queries.https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#add-keys.  
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export